# Unsorted results when using Array.sort() with two argument

Tags: c#

When I try two arguments with **Array.sort()** I get the unsorted list for one of the arguments.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Car[] MyAuto = new Car[5];
        MyAuto[0] = new Car("Rusty", 80, 1);
        MyAuto[1] = new Car("Mary", 40, 234);
        MyAuto[2] = new Car("Viper", 40, 34);
        MyAuto[3] = new Car("Mel", 40, 4);
        MyAuto[4] = new Car("Chicky", 40, 5);
        Array.Sort(MyAuto, new PetNameComparer());
        Console.WriteLine("Ordering by pet name:");
        foreach (Car C in MyAuto)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", C.CarID, C.PetName);
        }
    }
```

I get the following results with Two Arguments:

```
5-Chicky
234-Mary
4-Mel
1-Rusty
34-Viper
```

Although the names are alphabetically sorted, Numbers are not. while when I just use one argument to sort the list by  Numbers, it sorts it correctly:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Car[] MyAuto = new Car[5];
        MyAuto[0] = new Car("Rusty", 80, 1);
        MyAuto[1] = new Car("Mary", 40, 234);
        MyAuto[2] = new Car("Viper", 40, 34);
        MyAuto[3] = new Car("Mel", 40, 4);
        MyAuto[4] = new Car("Chicky", 40, 5);

        // I just used the Myauto variable which implements Icomparable 
        interface.

        Array.Sort(MyAuto);
        Console.WriteLine("Ordering by CarID);
        foreach (Car C in MyAuto)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", C.CarID, C.PetName);
        }
    }
```

I get the correct sorting:

```
1-Rusty
4-Mel
5-Chicky
34-Viper
234-Mary
```

Why I can't get correct multiple ID and Name sort orders like the following, while each of sort orders separately works fine?

```
1-Chicky
4-Mary
5-Mel
34-Rusty
234-Viperv
```

This is the Implementation of PetNameComparer()`

```
class PetNameComparer:IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        Car t1=x as Car;
        Car t2= y as Car;
        if (t1!=null&t2!=null)          
            return string.Compare(t1.PetName, t2.PetName);
            else          
                throw new ArgumentException("Parameter is not car");          
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the implementation of `PetNameComparer`

Comment: And what does `Car.CompareTo` do? Presumably it sounds by ID. Your "desired" order is impossible, as that would have to be changing the car name/ID - the car with ID 1 is *not* Chicky, it's Rusty.

Comment: To put it another way - it's like asking the people "Donald Trump", "Hillary Clinton", "Bernie Sanders" to be sorted by both first name and last name, and expecting a result of "Bernie Clinton", "Donald Sanders", "Hillary Trump". Would that make *any* sense to you?

Comment: So what do you actually want, to sort by ID or Name? If you have two separate, unrelated lists, sort each of them separately.

Comment: you can't use sorting for this

Comment: Ah... You are right, it's logically impossible ... my mistake

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this problem is not solvable since it's a logical contradiction