# How to send success message after each iteration

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am sending emails in a loop and iterating that loop again. Currently,  the success message is displaying after sending all emails using

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("message", resultMessage);
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
```

I want to display the success message after each successful iteration on the jsp page.

Iteration code in servlet class:

```
try {               
    for(int j=0;j<noOfEmailToSend;j++) {
        Iterator<String> sendersInputIterate = list.iterator();
        Iterator<String> subject1 = sub.iterator();

        while (sendersInputIterate.hasNext() && subject1.hasNext()) {   
            EmailFunction.sendEmail(ExchangeIP, port, sendersInputIterate.next(), toAddress, subject1.next(), content, uploadedFiles);  
            resultMessage = "The B-mail has been sent successfully :";
            Thread.sleep(sleeptime);
        }

        Thread.sleep(iterationInterval);
    }                                           
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();               
    resultMessage = "There were an error: " + ex.getMessage();
} finally {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("message", resultMessage);
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
}
```

Please suggest how to display this message after each iteration.

Comment: @coolgirl `finally` will **always** be executed ([ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44280902/unsorted-results-when-using-array-sort-with-two-argument)). So even if there is an `Exception`... Would be wrong to show a `SuccessMessage` there.

Comment: @FelixD. I guess you have misinterpreted what I've mentioned. I know that a finally will always be executed only in certain case of system.exit() or probably a malfunctioning of system or something, where it doesn't! The code above posted is sending a success message only once, and also in case of a failure it happens to send a success message. What I've suggested is to move the code from finally block to the loop where it the msg gets fired for every successful email sent!

Comment: That would make alot more sense :P - I guess this also is the answer so you may post that as a real answer.

Comment: I'm wondering where my previous comment went!

Comment: Yeah me too ^^ Was asking myself if I was to dumb to read but I cant check it anymore :D

Answer (score 1):

there is a fast solution,which is: instead of making the loop inside the servlet,
make the loop at client side to do an ajax requests, put your emails inside javascript array then iterate the array over loop then send them to servlet one by one,you can detect weather if the email is sent successfully or got a failure, the servlet can send 1 email per request
and the output stream can print one time per request

here is an example:

```
var emails=new Array();
emails.push("foo@foo.com");
emails.push("bar@bar.com");
emails.push("foo@bar.com");
$(document).ready(function(){
// first param is the url which will you send the param
//second param the email which will you send and in this case you have to pull it by request.getParameter("email");
third param the response which you got from servlet weather success or fail
for(i=0;i<emails.size();i++){
$.post("SendEmailServlet",{email: emails[i]},function(data){
 // third param the response from servlet
})
})
}
```

Comment: Thank you. bt i am  totally new to ajax..can u please explain with sample code to iterate on clientside.